# ImageWithSize on MPMediaItemArtwork returns very small coverart image (55 x 55 px)

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, mpmediaitem

I am trying to create a very simple music player (for small children) in Monotouch and have most of it working just great.

However when I iterate through MPMediaItems in a playlist and try to get their artwork I always get an image with size 55 x 55 pixels. When I listen to the songs in the builtin IPod application I can see that the stored artwork is larger than that.

Platform: Latest monodevelop and monotouch. iOS 4.2.3 on device

Code to get artwork of the first song in a playlist:

```
MPMediaItem[] songs = foundPlaylist.Items;
MPMediaItemArtwork artwork = (MPMediaItemArtwork)songs[0].ValueForProperty(MPMediaItemProperty.Artwork);
var imageRect = artwork.ImageCropRectangle;
UIImage artWorkImage = artwork.ImageWithSize (imageRect);
```

Am pretty stumped here. Any ideas?

Best regards

Soren

Comment: Look at the code https://github.com/erica/MPMediaItem-Properties by erica. This will defiantly help you for resolving your issue. This is tested code and it's working like charm for me.

Comment: Thanks Pragnesh. I'll take a look. But I am using monotouch c# code and not native Objective C. I have tried just creating a rectangle 256x256 like erica does in the code, but this only gets me a VERY pixelated image as the source image is only 55 x 55 pixels. So either I doing something weird wrong or monotouch has a bug. But thanks for the code ref!

Comment: could it be related to this: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=657866

Comment: Well, you never know :-D but the ImageWithSize takes a RectangleF and it works like it should, but the image seems to be scaled from a 55 x 55 image regardless of what the I set the rectangleF to.

Comment: Ok, I have now tested the code you pointed me to and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the pointer. I will investigate if this is a monotouch problem or my own fault :-D

Comment: Have filed a bug report #678480 on novells bugzilla if anybody is interested.

Comment: Tried doing the exact same thing. Getting the artwork of the first song in the first playlist. Works in XCode Objective-C, but in C# Monotouch the resulting artwork is still only 55 x 55 px. Bloody weird. I thought monotouch was only a thin wrapper on top of the Apple API. So either something weird is going on or I'm being completely daft..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oki, got it figured out.
Big thanks to Kangaroo on the monotouch chat!

There is a binding error in the imageWithSize method on MPMediaItemArtwork, so you need to message the selector directly. This is done in this way (to get a 256x256 image):

```
UIImage artWorkImage = (UIImage) Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_SizeF (artwork.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("imageWithSize:"), new SizeF (256, 256)));
```